# Python recursively search directory for presence of file

Tags: python, recursion

I need to search a small tree of directories for a specific filename and return 1 if found, and 0 if not.

I have tried to implement this using os.walk() but am unsure of the correct syntax. I am trying to build a function using the following function definition as a base:

```
def file_find(filename, search_path):
   file_found = 0
   if exists(join(path, filename)):
       return 1
   else:
      return 0
```

This works OK but I need to make it recursive. I think a combination of a for loop and os.walk is the answer but not sure how to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> os.walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False) Generate
>   the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down
>   or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top
>   (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames,
>   filenames)

so...

```
def find_file(filename, search_path):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(search_path):
        if filename in filenames:
            return 1
    return 0
```

`os.walk()` takes care of the recursion through subfolders for you, if your task is to implement the same behaviour using explicit recusion, then you shouldn't use `os.walk()` and instead look into `os.listdir()`

Comment: Perfect, many thanks. It seems the problems I was having with os.walk() were actually problems elsewhere in my script, got it working now by simplifying.